# How to Replace timer with turn based onClick in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a TicTacToe online multiplayer game in Android Studio using Firebase, below is the code I am using for the buttons (1 of the 9 blocks of TicTacToe). Right now I am using a timer to stop the user from clicking any other buttons after he once click the button to give the other user time to click. But I want to make it so that one user won't be able to click any button till the other user clicks a button. Is there a way to do so?
The default values of nothing & face & a1 is "zero" and default value of added is "one" whereas rface is just a string variable getting its value from "face".

```
//below clicking
        a1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //below
                //starting if condition
                if (ra1.equals(nothing)){

                    if (rface.equals(nothing)){
                        a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
                        Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a1");
                        refChild.setValue("round");
                        refChild = ref2.child("face");
                        refChild.setValue("one");
                    }

                    else if (rface.equals(added)) {
                        a1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.crossed);
                        Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a1");
                        refChild.setValue("cross");
                        refChild = ref2.child("face");
                        refChild.setValue("zero");
                    }
                    //timer below

                    a1.setClickable(false);
                    a2.setClickable(false);
                    a3.setClickable(false);
                    b1.setClickable(false);
                    b2.setClickable(false);
                    b3.setClickable(false);
                    c1.setClickable(false);
                    c2.setClickable(false);
                    c3.setClickable(false);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            a1.setClickable(true);
                            a2.setClickable(true);
                            a3.setClickable(true);
                            b1.setClickable(true);
                            b2.setClickable(true);
                            b3.setClickable(true);
                            c1.setClickable(true);
                            c2.setClickable(true);
                            c3.setClickable(true);
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                    //timer above
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Variable names which end in a number usually indicate that you should use an array or List.

Comment: As to your actual question, do you have a computer player or is this built for two human players? Are the two human players playing on the same device or over a network?

Comment: Your variable names are a little confusing. What do `ra1` and `rface` mean? What is `nothing` and `added`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having two different `OnClickListener`s rather than an if statement. One for Xs and the other for Os. Then you can set the listener back and forth. For example, at the end of the `OnClickListener` for X, it calls `setOnClickListener()` using the one for Os.

Comment: can you please provide me with some code example that would be really helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with this algorithm for my solution:

```
online=0;
offline=1;


if (online!=offline){
    offline=random;
    online=offline;
    if(shape=0)
    {
        click(set round);
    }
    else if(shape=1)
    {
        click(set cross);
    }
}
```

where shaper is another integer which I am using as a switch.